# in javascript constructor, how to put paramterized function inside object scope?

Tags: javascript, object, scope

have been using a pretty much loving Crockford's `constructor`, but, having problems adding scoped functions to the object:

```
'use strict';

var Constructor = function( params ) {
  let config = params,
      data = params.datum,
      action = function(a,b) { return config.actions[a](b); };
  return Object.freeze({
    action: action
  });
};

var cns = Constructor({
      datum: 123,
      actions: {
        getData: function(b) { return data; }
      } 
});   

cns.action('getData',0);
```

get `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`.

how do I have a function as an argument to the constructor and have that function have the scope of object?

Comment: You cannot change the scope of a function, and `data` is not in the scope of that `getData` function. You may want to use `this.data` instead, and use `config.actions[a].call(params, b)`

Comment: @Bergi - that works, except it's pulling `data` from `params` instead of the object. have changed code to clarify problem.

Comment: `data` is a local variable in the `Constructor` function, not a property on an object. You cannot access it from outside.

Comment: I really wonder why you want that function as an argument to the constructor? That's a very unusual pattern, and might be the root of your confusion.

Comment: @Bergi - for a flux-like Store object. each store is handling its own actions, and the actions need access to the objects innards. another approach may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following [Crockford's private members in JavaScript post](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html), then `getData` should be a "privileged" function (a function that has access to private members such as `data`). Therefore, this function should follow the "privileged" pattern given in his post ([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/n2tes8on/)).

```
var Constructor = function (params) {
    var config = params;
    var data = params.data;

    // Privileged function pattern: 
    // By using a closure, this method has access to private members.
    this.getData = function (b) {
        return data;
    };
};

// Note: Changed to `new` in order to instantiate the class
var cns = new Constructor({
    data: 123
});   

console.log(cns.getData(0));
```

Comment: understood. but the problem is that I have a lot of object that have different privileged methods - this means I would need a unique constructor for each object, which is pretty absurd

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way seems to be to manually pass object guts to the function, either with `call` or as an extra argument. since I'm dodging `this`, am using the extra argument, here `self`. `self` is not exposed to the world at large, only to the functions that need to see it.

```
'use strict';

var Constructor = function( params ) {
  let config = params,
      data = params.datum,
      self = { data: data },
      action = function(a,b) { return config.actions[a](b,self); };
  return Object.freeze({
    action: action
  });
};

var cns = Constructor({
      datum: 123,
      actions: {
        getData: function(b,s) { return s.data; }
      } 
});   

cns.action('getData',0);
```